# File sync or replication

Tags: file, synchronization, microsoft-distributed-file-system

What is the easiest way to sync or replicate files over a network? I am running a few servers in a rack for load balancing and wish to mirror content.

For example, I have Server 1 where I do my FTP uploads to. Server 2 is another node. The manual way is for me to also do FTP uploads to Server 2 but I am sure it can be done automatically without my presence or without the user logged in.

I have tried SyncToy but it just doesn't run when the user is not logged in. I have to manually run it.

Are there better ways? I saw Microsoft DFS but it is just too complicated for me to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SyncBack.](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse-features.html)
There's a light-weight version (SE) which is free and a Pro version.

Comment: I tried SyncBack SE but it seems the schedule is just not syncing the files properly. I was able to setup a Scheduled Task and it ran with no errors but the files are not synced.

It only works if I do it manually. Anything I should take note? Anyway, can SyncBack schedule run without user logged in?

The folders I am syncing is from Network folder to a local folder.

Comment: I setup my task action as follows "C:\Program Files (x86)\2BrightSparks\SyncBack\SyncBack.exe" -m "testproject"

The task ran with no errors but no synchronization was done. Next I run that line straight in Start>Run and it worked. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: I used to have SyncBack setup for backing up my laptop on an external hard disk. This was a year ago. I haven't used SyncBak for a long time after reinstalling Windows after a virus attack. As far as I remember you need to specify the source/destination directories, set up a schedule and SyncBack used to sync my directories automatically at the scheduled time (I think I used to be logged in, when this used to happen). I'm not sure if anything changed in the newer versions.